# How to use mongoose populate and moongose pagination together?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

Full code here: https://github.com/kenpeter/dl_r18_img_back

There is a [nice package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate) to hook pagination with mongoose:

According to [this](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/issues/101), it seems I can use populate with pagination, but I am not able to get it working.

```
list: function(page = 1, limit = 100){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      let options = {
        page: parseInt(page),
        limit: parseInt(limit),
        sort:{
          createdDate: -1 //Sort by Date Added DESC
        }
      };

      /*
      Image
        .paginate({}, options)
        .then(function(res) {
          resolve && resolve(res);
        });
      */

      // NOT WOKRING!!!!!
      Image
        .populate('category')
        .execPopulate()
        .paginate({}, options)
        .then(function(res) {
          resolve && resolve(res);
        });

      /*
      Image
        .find({})
        ..populate('category')
        .exec()
        .then(function(res) {
          resolve && resolve(res);
        });
      */
    });
```

As you can see there are 2 commented-out code block `Image.xxxxx`. They are working individually.

How do I put them together?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to put a `populate` option for populating.

Here is a snippet from the doc:

> ```
> var options = {
>     select:   'title date author',
>     sort:     { date: -1 },
>     populate: 'author',
>     lean:     true,
>     offset:   20, 
>     limit:    10 };
> ```

maybe use `populate : "category"`